# How do I hide electron default menu

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, electron

I have made a project using Ionic 4 and Electron. I don't want to show the default menu items as highlighted in the picture below.

[image]

This is my `electron-starter.js` code below. I have tried with  `mainWindow.removeMenu();` , `mainWindow.removeMenu(null);` , `mainWindow.setAutoHideMenuBar(hide);` but nothing worked at all.

How can I achieve this?

```
const electron = require('electron');
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app;
// Module to create native browser window.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1200, height: 700});
        //mainWindow.removeMenu(null);
       //mainWindow.setAutoHideMenuBar(hide);



    // and load the index.html of the app.
    const startUrl = process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL || url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../www/index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        });
    mainWindow.loadURL(startUrl);
    // Open the DevTools.

    // uncomment below code to open console by default
    // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null
    })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
});

app.on('activate', function () {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Comment: did you try this mainWindow.setMenu(null) ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the [application menu](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu#menusetapplicationmenumenu) to null

```
const { Menu } = require('electron')

Menu.setApplicationMenu(null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set browser window menu to null.

```
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1200, height: 700 });
mainWindow.setMenu(null);
```

Comment: Great worked. Thanks